# How to call a javascript function on submit to assign a value to an input? (ACE Editor)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, ace-editor

My goal is to send the code inside the ACE Editor to as a variable to the `send.php` PHP file. I tried this in many different methods but I can't assign the code inside the editor to the form input.

---

**JavaScript**

This javascript function should assign a value to an element with the `id="code"`, which is: `<input type="hidden" id="code" value="" />`.

`editor.getSession().getValue();` returns the code that is inside the editor.

```
<head>
 <script>

   function getVal() {
   document.getElementById('code').value = editor.getSession().getValue();
   }

 </script>
</head>
```

**HTML**

Now, `<form onsubmit="getVal();"` should execute `function getVal()` when a user submits the form, so that the `code` input will have a value when sending the inputs to the `send.php` file.

```
<body>

  <div>
     <form onsubmit="getVal();" method="post" action="send.php">

        <label for="Name">From:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
        <label for="Address">To:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" />
        <label for="Subject">Subject:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" />

        <input type="hidden" id="code" value="" />

        <div id="editor"> //ACE Editor
        </div>

        <input type="submit">

     </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try to give the function in submit button, like onclick="return getVal();". Also check the hidden field should have the correct value then only retun true else return false.

Comment: I did that, it still doesn't work. I added value to the input `<input type="hidden" id="code" value="a" />` and checked if it has this value in the js function - it returns false. Maybe the problem is with the `document.getElementById('code').value`?

Comment: can you just rename the textbox id and also put some name for it bcoz you need to get the value in php right? this have no issue document.getElementById('code').value

Comment: @JobinJose what textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is the one I needed in order to make this work:

```
function getVal()
{
  var editor = ace.edit("editor"); 
  // this line is necessary
  // "editor" is the id of the ACE editor div

  var code = editor.getSession().getValue();

  document.getElementById('code').value = code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, editor.getSession().getValue() is null so it writes nothing!

Comment: It's not null because it gets all the code inside the editor (after the user wrote some code).

Comment: Did you try to print its value to an alert or to console.log?
Before i tried to make the hidden input to text and instead editor.getSession().getValue(); I wrote 'test';
When i submit the form it wrote test to the input and then it submit so the problem must be editor.getSession().getValue()!!

Comment: `document.getElementById('code').value = 'test';
<form onsubmit="getVal();" method="post" action="http://www.google.com">
<input type="text" id="code" value="" />`

Comment: You were right, I tried to check if `document.getElementById('code')` is working by doing `if(document.getElementById('code').value == "a")` and `<input type="text" id="code" value="a" />` but it returned false for some reason so I thought that's the problem.